# Join two tables with comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, group-concat, find-in-set

I have 2 tables as below

Notes Table

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ nid      ║    forDepts     ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ 1,2,4           ║
║ 2        ║ 4,5             ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Positions Table

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id       ║    name         ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Executive       ║
║ 2        ║ Corp Admin      ║
║ 3        ║ Sales           ║
║ 4        ║ Art             ║
║ 5        ║ Marketing       ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

I am looking to query my Notes table and associate the 'forDepts' column with values from the Positions table.

The output should be:

```
    ╠══════════╬════════════════════════════╣
    ║ 1        ║ Executive, Corp Admin, Art ║
    ║ 2        ║ Art, Marketing             ║
    ╚══════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

I know that the database should be normalized but I cannot change the database structure for this project.

This is going to be used to export a excel file with the code below.

```
<?PHP

    $dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
    mysql_select_db('exAdmin', $dbh1);


    function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }
    
    $filename = "eXteres_summary_" . date('m/d/y') . ".xls";
    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    //header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    
    $flag = false;


    $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT p.name, c.company, n.nid, n.createdOn, CONCAT_WS(' ',c2.fname,c2.lname), n.description 
     FROM notes n 
     LEFT JOIN Positions p ON p.id = n.forDepts
     LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.userid = n.clientId
     LEFT JOIN companies c2 ON c2.userid = n.createdBy"
     , $dbh1);
 

    
    while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
        if(!$flag) {
            $colnames = array(
                'Created For' => "Created For",
                'Company' => "Company",
                'Case ID' => "Case ID",
                'Created On' => "Created On",
                'Created By' => "Created By",
                'Description' => "Description"
            );
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($colnames)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
    }
    

        $row['createdOn'] = date('m-d-Y | g:i a', strtotime($row['createdOn']));
    
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }
  exit;
  
  ?>
```

This code outputs only the first value of 'forDepts'

Exa: Executive (instead of Executive, Corp Admin, Art)

Can this be accomplished by CONCAT or FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: If you can't change the bad database layout, you should probably fix it OUTSIDE of the database, i.e. you query the data you get and exchange the ids with their text values in PHP before pushing them to the Excel file. Sadly, the nasty database layout forces you to create nasty layout-fixing code.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.nid,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.id) DepartmentName
FROM    Notes a
        INNER JOIN Positions b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.forDepts) > 0
GROUP   BY a.nid
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d26100/2)

Comment: If a row in the `Notes` table have a blank value  for column `forDepts` then result missing that row.

Comment: @JohnWoo What is the purpose of `> 0` at the end of the join ? Is that related to performance?

Answer (score 16):

```
Table 1
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ nid      ║    forDepts     ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ 1,2,4           ║
║ 2        ║ 4,5             ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
Table 2
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id       ║    name         ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Executive       ║
║ 2        ║ Corp Admin      ║
║ 3        ║ Sales           ║
║ 4        ║ Art             ║
║ 5        ║ Marketing       ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝

SELECT * FROM table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON find_in_set(t2.id, 
t1.forDepts)

Output 

 ╠══════════╬════════════════════════════╣
 ║ 1        ║ Executive, Corp Admin, Art ║
 ║ 2        ║ Art, Marketing             ║
 ╚══════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the query takes ages to complete when there are large amount of data.