# joining of two mysql table with PHP in single query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following two tables. I want to join them in a single query.I am able to do it with inner join if the Blog_Category_Id in Blog table is a single value. But when it comes as a multiple value how can i do it?

[First Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR3yC.png)

[Second Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82XmQ.png)

Below is the result table which i want to show...

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx0iB.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.* ,GROUP_CONCAT(bc.blog_category ORDER BY bc.id) blog_category
FROM blog b 
INNER JOIN blog_category bc ON FIND_IN_SET(bc.id, b.blog_category_id)
GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: Please consider to add some explanation and/or reference to documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can you `FIND_IN_SET` in `INNER JOIN`
Check here You may got answer

[MySQL Join two tables with comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101550/mysql-join-two-tables-with-comma-separated-values)