# SQL Query for Joining 2 tables where one of them has multiple values in one field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

Tables 1 as below

```
User_Option_Experience


user_id | teaching_in 
        |  
111     |   1,2,3
112     |   1,4
113     |   4,2
```

Tables 2 as below

```
Teaching_in


IdTeaching | name
           |  
1          |   Biology
2          |   Chemistry
3          |   Mathematics
```

Now what i want is to have an output of all the names of subjects a User (Teacher) teaches in because one user as seen from the table can teach many subjects

For example I want all the subjects for user with id 111

I tried this but no success as it returns only one record

```
select teaching_in.name 
  from teaching_in 
  left 
  join users_options_experience 
    on user_options_experience.teaching_in = teaching_in.IdTeachingin 
 where user_options_experience.user_id = 15605
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us the query what you have tried so far? Please show us the expected output as well.

Comment: There's no need to show us what you've tried. Instead, focus your efforts on normalising your schema.

Comment: This is a poor way of storing data. Look up how to structure a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I cant change the database because this is how i found it when i started work here.

Comment: Holy cow, what an ugly database design!

Comment: Now you're in charge, you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  a.user_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.IdTeaching) DepartmentName
FROM    User_Option_Experience a
        INNER JOIN Teaching_in b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.IdTeaching , a.teaching_in) > 0
GROUP   BY a.user_id

Answered by 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101550/mysql-join-two-tables-with-comma-separated-values)

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.name 
FROM    User_Option_Experience a
        INNER JOIN Teaching_in b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.teaching_in , b.IdTeaching )
WHERE a.user_id=111;
```

Use FIND_IN_SET function of mysql

Hope this will help you.