# I need Comma separated values of mysql table on separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as following

Table products

```
-product_id-        -categorie ids-
  1                   2,4,5,6
  2                   1,4,3
  4                    3,5
```

Table categories

```
c-category_id-       -(catname)-
  1                  cat1
  2                  cat2
  3                  cat3
  4                  cat4
  5                  cat5
  6                  cat6
```

I need result in this format

```
-product_id-        -categories-
  1                  cat2
  1                  cat4
  1                  cat5
  1                  cat6
  2                  cat1
  2                  cat4
  .                    .
  .                    .
  .                    .
```

Comment: Good idea to fix that! Comma separated values only cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: You should go with this idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101550/mysql-join-two-tables-with-comma-separated-values?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.product_id,
        b.catname
FROM    products a
        INNER JOIN category b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.category_id, a.categorie_ids) > 0
            ORDER BY a.product_id
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02efca/5

Comment: welcome!! @GirishPatil If you got your answer you can accept it