# How to retrieve stored data by delimiter ( ; ) in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 Tables Like these:

```
region Table:
+----------+-------------+
|region_id | region_name |
+----------+-------------+
|1         | RN1         |
|2         | RN2         |
|3         | RN3         |
+----------+-------------+
```

and

```
role Table:
+----------+-------------+
|role_id   | role_name   |
+----------+-------------+
|1         | admin       |
|2         | software    |
|3         | network     |
+----------+-------------+
```

In my HTML form I get region_id and role_id from Administrator and store using PHP in MySQL table like this:

```
useraccess Table:
+--------+-----------+
|role_id | region_id |
+--------+-----------+
|1       | 1;2;3     |
|2       | 1         |
|3       | 1;2       |
+--------+-----------+
```

Well, the problem is I don't know how to write a query that can retrieve region_name(s) from region table using useraccess table.
for example: when role_id = 1 then region_id is 1;2;3 so instead of 1,2,3 I want to show RN1,RN2,RN3 in my HTML page.

I tried to use for-loop using PHP but it has own limitation and doesn't work correctly. also I used MySQL SPLIT_STR() function but maybe I can't get the result. I will appreciate help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Normalize your data

Comment: If you had at least used comma instead of semicolon, then you could apply a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/q/19101550/1427878 You could still dynamically replace semicolon by comma first using string functions, I suppose, but that would likely make an already bad approach, even worse. _Proper_ solution, as already said: Normalize your data.

Comment: When you need to extract Nth element from delimited text then you'd use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CSV_value, 'delimiter', N), 'delimiter', -1)`. If N is greater than the amount of values in delimited text then you will receive the most last value. So you'd check the amount of delimiters in the value. PS. I agree too that the normalization is the only safe solution.

Comment: @CBroe The value may contain inner comma, and FIND_IN_SET will be non-applicable.

Comment: @Akina the individual values are IDs from the `region` table here though, so I doubt we would actually have to expect non-integers here at any point.

Comment: You urgently need to read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad). You've got as far as making a link table (your `useraccess` table) with the IDs to match up in it. The only mistake is that each pair of values should be in one row of the table. e.g. there should be _three_ rows containing role_id `1`, each with a different region_id in the other column. Then you could easily select, search, filter etc on the values _properly_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for this issue you need to have a **common column** between two tables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this query:

```
SELECT ua.role_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(r.region_name SEPARATOR ',') AS region_names
  FROM useraccess ua
  JOIN region r ON FIND_IN_SET(r.region_id, replace(ua.region_id,";",","))
  GROUP BY ua.role_id;
```

Comment: Comma or Semicolon, this is not problem. I just want to show RN1,RN2,RN3 instead of 1,2,3 ( delimiter is not important , or ; )

Comment: @waepdurmia this will show RN1,RN2,RN3

Answer (score 0):

This instruction works better:

```
SELECT  a.role_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.region_name ORDER BY b.region_id) RegionAccessName
    FROM    useraccess a
    INNER JOIN region b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(b.region_id, a.region_id) > 0
    GROUP   BY a.role_id
```

but instead of return:

```
RN1,RN2,RN3
RN1
RN1,RN
```

Return:

```
RN1,RN2,RN3
RN1,RN2,RN3
RN1,RN2,RN3
```

In PHP Code I use this:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){;
    echo $row2["RegionAccessName"];
}
```